# C++ Error inserting values in Singly Linked List (E0137)

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I've created a singly linked list, and it was running perfectly, that is until I changed my "basic" data structure from a single *int* value to a variety of variables.

The error occurs in the *insertAtEnd* function, when I try to store the data it gets from the parameters on the temp node.

```
temp->nome = n;
temp->morada = m;
temp->telefone = t;
temp->idade = i;
```

The int value shows no error, but the char[] ones get the error "E0137 - expression must be a modifiable lvalue".

> List.h

```
struct node
{
    char nome[20];
    char morada[30];
    char telefone[9];
    Int idade;
    node *next;
};

class LinkedList
{
private:
    node *head;
    node *tail;
public:
    LinkedList();
    ~LinkedList();
    void insertAtEnd(char n[20], char m[30], char t[9], int i);
    void insertAtStart(char n[20], char m[30], char t[9], int i);
    void display(void);
    void deleteFirst(void);
    void deleteLast(void);
    void deleteAtPosition(int pos);
};
```

> List.cpp

```
(...)
LinkedList::LinkedList()
{
    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
}
void LinkedList::insertAtEnd(char n[20], char m[30], char t[9], int i)
{
    node *temp = new node;
    temp->nome = n;
    temp->morada = m;
    temp->telefone = t;
    temp->idade = i;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = temp;
        tail = temp;
        temp = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = temp;
        tail = temp;
    }
}
(...)
```

> Main.cpp

```
(...)
LinkedList lista;
    char nome[20];
    char morada[30];
    char telefone[9];
    int idade;
    (...)
    switch (op) {
        case 1:
            cout << "Inserir nome: ";
            cin >> nome;
            cout << "Inserir morada: ";
            cin >> morada;
            cout << "Inserir telefone: ";
            cin >> telefone;
            cout << "Inserir idade: ";
            cin >> idade;
            lista.insertAtEnd(nome, morada, telefone, idade);
            break;
(...)
```

Those are some blocks of code from my project I think are relevant, I'm almost sure there's nothing else on it that would matter to this issue, but if you do think so, comment and I'll edit it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Debugger. Use a debugger.  A debugger allows you to single-step through your code, *watching* values in variables.  Often, using a debugger is faster than posting to StackOverflow and *waiting* for somebody to inspect or debug your code for you.

Comment: When debugging linked lists, drawing the list (pen/pencil) is often very helpful.  This will help you find pointer related issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code generates the following error: In member function ‘void LinkedList::insertAtEnd(char*, char*, char*, int)’: error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘char*’ to ‘char [20]’. You must copy each value from your function parameter to your node(I mean do temp->nome[0] = n[0] for each value in your array). You can change your node structure to use pointers instead of arrays and this would become easier.
If you want to find out more, check the following link :

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_passing_arrays_to_functions.htm